# Google Earth Engine

Tags: java, google-earth-engine

```
var savi = cloud_free_composite.expression("((1+0.2)(nir - red)) / (0.2 + nir + red)", {
    'nir': cloud_free_composite.select("B5"),
    'red': cloud_free_composite.select("B4")
}).rename("SAVI_SC");
```

It gives this error: Expected ')' and instead saw 'var'
Missing ';' before statement

Answer (score 0):

The error specifies a 'var', which unlikely is your 'var savi'. Can you please provide the rest of your script.